# Break long number (no space) around an image in html

Tags: html, css, word-break

I have tried to break the long number `111111111111111111112222222222222222222222333333333333333333344444444444444444445555555555555555` around an image, but it is not right.

Please check the html below.

```
<td valign="top" colspan='1' style="width:1120px; word-break:break-all;">
  <img src="file://#step_image" width="140" style="float: right"/>
  111111111111111111112222222222222222222222333333333333333333344444444444444444445555555555555555
</td>
```

And the result is like this:

[image]

Why does it have the space inside?

Comment: kindly provide code to get your problem more conveniently.

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle? (p.s. do not mix single & double quotes in same HTML)

Comment: I don't know JSFiddle, and I am not good in html.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TUGD6/1/
@Raptor: Please check the link. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting question. Unicode specifies that the break should not happen within a number: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr14/

And it's discussed more here in a webkit bug report: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=108347#c22

So I think the answer is that CSS explicitly does not support what you want because Unicode says that it shouldn't. I have hit very similar constraints in the past. In that case I had to parse the string to insert a [Zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) between all characters. That would work for you if you have the ability to modify the number string like that.

When you set [`word-wrap:break-word`](http://jsfiddle.net/TUGD6/3/) and add the zero width spaces you get this:
[image: digits run right up to the image]

(Maybe someday they'll add word-wrap: break-ALL-i-am-serious!, but I wouldn't hold my breath for it.)

Comment: Thanks! I will try with "Zero-width space".

Comment: The problem is solved by inserting "zero-width space" ("\u200b") into the string (and also set "word-break:break-word"). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

You can break work using css:-

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

Try this.

Comment: It is ok if it is a text. But it is long number without space.

Comment: I have edited my question by adding real image from my app. Thanks.

Comment: Please goto->jsfiddle.net, then put your html and javascript and css then save it and give me the link. Because your question is not clear.

Comment: I have updated it http://jsfiddle.net/TUGD6/2/. I think you are talking about red td.

Comment: Yes, about red td, merging the long number and image, but it has space.

Comment: "It will also work for long number without space." No, it won't. Numbers break differently from words.

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be a table cell?

```
 <p><img align="right" src="#" /> All of your text here..............................</p>
```